# How to destroy global model in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, odata, sapui5

I'm trying to destroy global model but with no luck.
I have button for filter which looks like this:

```
navToSecond : function (oEvent){
        var oObject = this.getView().byId("inp").getValue();
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oObject, "Filters");
        this.getRouter().navTo("second"); 
        },
```

In the second view I have smart table with filtered oData after I fill input fields in first view. Then I press button to navigate back on the first page and I want to refresh or destroy global model and read input from fields again. Then it should send new request URL.

I was trying like this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("Filters").destroy();
```

or

```
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("Filters").refresh(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want use `destroy` and `refresh` function,you must confirm `sap.ui.getCore().getModel("Filters")` result object have this two function.
I guessed you can try this：

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(null, "Filters");
```

or:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel("", "Filters");
```

Comment: When I try your snippet, still nothing happens. After I change values in input field and press button again, no new query is created.

Comment: I suggest you to read SAPUI5 document ,perhaps find out other way to solve this problem

Comment: Setting a model is not the same as executing a query, it just attached the model (including any potential data) to a view, and the children of the view.

Answer (score 1):

The question of this thread is "How to destroy global model in SAPUI5"

Ying Yi answered it correctly. If you unset the model, all references to the model will be deleted and the garbage collector can do his job.

But your real problem is to fire the executing of the query to update your table. Destroy and recreate models is the wrong way. Work with events how I descriped it in your other thread to this subject.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Once a model has been destroyed from `sap.ui.getCore()` there's a flag indicating that the model has been destroyed.